# Insert image url into rmarkdown latex template

Tags: r, r-markdown

is there perhaps a way to insert an image url into a rmarkdown template latex file that produces a pdf?

I am using Rstudio, and I am trying to edit the default latex file which it calls, to add a url figure into the title.

Ideally I want the figure to be called from the url, and not created in the folder, as e.g. discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5433/can-i-use-an-image-located-on-the-web-in-a-latex-document).

Any ideas how this could be achieved?

Comment: Do you want to add the figure directly in rmarkdown or later in Latex?

Comment: @Alex It should be called later in latex. i.e. the figure is not part of the Rmarkdown code - it is directly built into the pdf from latex.

Comment: Then I would say this is more a Latex related question.

Comment: Look here: http://tex.stackexchange.com